# How to check if time setting is automatic on Android?

Tags: android, flutter

I am using flutter to make android android app. I am trying to check whether time setting in android is automatic or not. In Java we can check this using following code below:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){

 if(Settings.Global.getInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
 Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME,0) == 0){
        
        // Go to settings activity
   }
 else{
        // Do your stuff
     }

  }
```

I want to know how can we implement above thing in flutter.

Comment: Pretty much paste the above `getInt` code into a method channel handler and return the `int` - see [Calling native code from flutter](https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: see step 3a: https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: @Richard I have been through documentation actually I am using VS code for development so how can I create java file in it.

Comment: Grab a copy of Android Studio.

Comment: @Richard could u please provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [datetime_settings](https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_setting) package.

Again this package works for Android devices only.